# Install dependencies from local directory using python setuptools

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, setuptools, distutils

When a package is installed (by using python setup.py install), the dependencies are fetched from The Python Package index (pypi.python.org). But my target host doesn't have access to internet. I have put dependencies under a local directory as shown below.

```
/foo-package
    -dependencies/
         -requests/
         -lxml/
```

Is there anyway to install all these packages under dependencies directory by running `python setup.py install`?

Comment: maybe the topic below would be helpful for you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982406/how-can-i-make-setuptools-or-distribute-install-a-package-from-the-local-file

Comment: I don't see any solution for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is:

> How do I link previously downloaded dependencies with python and `setup.py`?

Your answer is in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123314/python-equivalent-of-node-jss-npm-link-to-use-local-development-versions-of-req). At the time of this writing, to top two answers aggregated to the solution I needed.

If you provide more detail, I will gladly update my answer.